# How to enable a logrotation with Jenkins

Tags: permissions, cron, log, logrotate, jenkins

I need to enable the logrotate service with Jenkins in order to rotate its log files (/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log).
So, I configured a script in /etc/logrotate.d with right permissions:

```
/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log {
        hourly
        copytruncate
        missingok
        rotate 8
        compress
        delaycompress
        size 5G
}
```

The permissions are 644 and the owner is root as for every logrotate script.

The logrotate service works correctly but not for Jenkins. No log files are rotated!

So, I tried to insert the command directly in root's crontab:

```
0 * * * * logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.d/jenkins
```

But also this command doesn't work at all even if the cron service works correctly each hour as per cron logs:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep logrotate
[...]
Jun  4 09:00:01 CI-prod CRON[11794]: (root) CMD (logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.d/jenkins)
Jun  4 10:00:01 CI-prod CRON[525]: (root) CMD (logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.d/jenkins)
```

However, if I manually execute the logrotate command (logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.d/jenkins), it works well and the Jenkins logs are rotated with no problem as per script.

Please, can you help me?

Here are other useful info:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- Jenkins version: 2.121.2
- Java version: 1.8.0_121

Comment: what steps here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610924/how-to-enable-log-rotation-in-jenkins-for-weekly and here : https://qamag.net/stop-that-huge-jenkins-log/ have you followed?

Comment: Could you use absolute path and redirect logrorate output? 0 * * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.d/jenkins > /tmp/outfile.log 2>&1 this could help to find out what goes wrong.

Comment: @Lety: perfect! I found out the problem! I redirected the error output to a temp log and I noticed that the system was unable to locate the logrotate command. I fixed the command in crontab and now it works well!

Comment: @roghan you are welcome :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

crontab has restricted environment, so try with absolute path and redirect command output into a file, this will help you in case of errors.

> 0 * * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.d/jenkins >
>   /tmp/outfile.log 2>&1